# How do I create a patch from diff between revisions using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn, diff, patch

I'm working on a project where Subversion is used to maintain version control. I use TortoiseSVN to access the project repository.

Some changes were made between two revisions on a project (let's call them rev1 and rev2), and I want to be able to apply these changes to a working copy somewhere that temporarily does not have access to the repository.

I right-clicked on a project folder, clicked 'SVN show log', selected the two revisions and selected 'Show changes as unified diff'.

This causes a window to be shown, displaying output that very much looks like a patch file that I could save. Unfortunately, I find that there is no option in the window that lets me save this as a patch file.

How can I create the patch file?

Comment: Just select all, copy, paste into a new text document, save with .patch extension, and then "apply patch" on the other side. (careful with paths - choose the right folder when applying)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The next version of TortoiseSVN (1.7.x) will have that save option. In the meantime, you can configure a plain text editor as your unified diff viewer:

```
Settings dialog->External Programs->Unified Diff Viewer
```

There you could, for example, specify `notepad.exe` as your diff viewer.

Comment: My patch has binary files, but the text file wasn't displaying these. I assume that they won't be saved in the patch?

Comment: the unified diff format can't handle binary content. That's why those are not included in a patch file (which is in unified diff format).

Comment: Is this feature available yet? Which version of TortoiseSVN would we need?

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve you goal is to right click on the revision in the TortoiseSVN log and choose "Merge revision to...". Then you select you local working project and click OK.