# How to create patch file between two revisions in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn, patch, revision, unified-diff

I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.7 and want to create patch file between two revisions.

I've searched, but these threads [How do I create a patch from diff between revisions using TortoiseSVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009434/how-do-i-create-a-patch-from-diff-between-revisions-using-tortoisesvn) [Creating a patch between two revisions](http://svn.haxx.se/tsvnusers/archive-2010-01/0425.shtml) do not work for me, as `Show changes as unified diff` generates very simple file (not a patch file). Something like

> Index: myfile.txt
>
> ===================================================================

I read in [Viewing Differences](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-diff.html) that

> If you want to see the changes made to all files in a particular
>   revision in one view, you can use Unified-Diff output (GNU patch
>   format). This shows only the differences **with a few lines** of context.
>   It is harder to read than a visual file compare, but will show all the
>   changes together. From the Revision Log dialog select the revision of
>   interest, then select Show Differences as Unified-Diff from the
>   context menu.

I want to create a single patch file (or many patch files according to modified files) that contains useful diff information (like the menu context TortoiseSVN -> Create patch ...)

Answer (score 5):

If you use the "Show changes as unified diff" command, then TortoiseSVN shows all changes of the selected revision in a single file.

Now simply use the "File / Save as" command to save the changes to a ".patch" or ".diff" file and there you have your patch file.